# understand a JS non obvious oneliner. Comma separator

Tags: javascript

i do not understand this line of javascript :

(i is a loop counter)

```
var m;

t[i] == '@' ? m = '' : t[i] == '_' ? m = null : (c = t[i].charAt(0), m = c == '@' || c == '_' ? t[i].substring(1) : t[i])
```

i can understand the `value == other ? true : false` trick, but i am totally mess by the nesting of more of one of these, the usage of the parenthesis, and of the comma.

can anyone guess what this think do ? i do not even have a sample usage :/ as the calling is buggy...

i also have a doubt on the `m = c == '@` clause must it be understood as `m = c ;` followed by `c == '@'` or is it `m = condition ? value if true : value if false) ?`

is the usage of the comma here is the same as using a ; ?

i think the aim is to strip some special chars @ and _ but it is so complicated!

i would have like to have many line with clear `if` clause rather than this one liner

thank you

Comment: The person who wrote that should be shot

Comment: It seems like code is try to validate whether the given string is valid email id or not, albeit a poor way of doing it. Should use RegEx for the purpose.

Comment: @tea_totaler Do you have a good regex pattern for JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always reformat a ternary operator statement to make it more readable. Formatting is one of the reasons you find `if` more readable:

```
t[i] == '@' ?
    m = '' :           // if it's an @
    t[i] == '_' ?      // else:
        m = null :     // if it's a _
        (              // else:
             c = t[i].charAt(0), // c = first character
             m =                 // m = one of the following:
                 c == '@' || c == '_' ?   // if @ or _ is first character
                     t[i].substring(1) :  // the string minus @ or _
                     t[i]                 // else the string itself
        )
```

Note that the result of the outermost ternary operator is discarded which is very, very ugly code. Instead it abuses the fact that the conditional part of the ternary operator can be an expression and does the assignment to m there.

Basically the above is a convoluted way of writing:

```
if (t[i] =='@') {
    m = '';
}
else if  (t[i] =='_') {
    m = null;
}
else {
    m = t[i].replace(/^[@_]/,''); // replace leading @ or _ with nothing
}
```

If you still need to do it with the ternary operator and without regex a better implementation would be this:

```
var str = t[i];
var c = str.charAt(0);

m = str == '@' ?             // if @
        '' :
    str == '_' ?             // if _
        null :
    (c == '@' || c == '_') ? // if starts with @ or _
        str.substring[1] :
                             // else don't modify the string
        str;
```

Note that in the above statement we assign the result of the ternary operator to `m` instead of doing the assignment within any of the evaluated statements. Which is the advantage of the ternary operator over `if` in the first place. Also note that the braces `()` are strictly speaking not necessary but they add to the readability of the code (IMHO).